# IdP initiated Single sign on POST binding

Tags: java, saml-2.0

My web application is looking for a way to redirect users to a service provider website(ABC Company) and I am in the process of implementing this using Idp initiated SSO. So idea is to create SAML assertion and bind it in a response which will be sent to SP(ABC Company) and once it is validated, user will be able to access Service Provider(ABC Company). Does anyone have any starting primer document on how to do this in java and what libraries are good to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often find that Idp initiated SSO is not the best solution. Instead of the IDP initiating the SSO, just redirect the user to the SP, the SP will see that the use is no authenticated and start SSO with the IDP.

Is there a reason you want to have the IDP initiate it?

If you really want to do IDP-initiated SSO there are many software that can do this. If you want to have it embedded in you appliation, have a look at the [Spring SAML module](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) og OpenSAML library(demands a very good understanding of SAML, examples [here](http://mylifewithjava.blogspot.no/search?q=opensaml))
You can also use thrid party sotware that only require setup and configuration. for example [OpenAM](http://openam.forgerock.org/)

Comment: That's what SP supports, SP wants us(IdP) to send them an assertion.

Comment: yogsma i'm in the same situation as you. Did you find any examples of IdP-first SSO implementations in java?
I also bought @Stefan Rasmusson book just to realize later that it covers the topic from SP point of view, my fault for not reading carefully, anyway I think it's gonna be useful in the future.